# Add last line from two csv files to two different mysql tables

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have two different csv files that are filled up with data (more than 1 Hz). They are looking like this:

```
date_time,V1,V2,V3
2020-06-12 15:30:00,13.2,3.8,5.6
2020-06-12 15:31:00,13.3,3.1,5,1
```

and

```
date_time,V1,V2
2020-06-12 15:28:00,5.4,8.3
2020-06-12 15:28:30,1.8,2.9
```

From each file I would like to read the last line every 5 or 10 seconds and add it to a table in a mysql db. The last line from the first file should be added to table `db1` and the last line of file two should be added to `db2`. What I tried is the following (only for the first file):

```
import subprocess
import mysql.connector as mysql
import time

db = mysql.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "bla"
    database = "data"
)
cursor = db.cursor()

while (1):
    last_line = subprocess.check_output(["tail", "-1", "/home/pi/output/test1.txt"])
    query = "INSERT INTO db1 (date_time, V1, V2, V3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    cursor.execute(query, last_line)
    db.commit()
    time.sleep(5)
```

But I get the error: 
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; Check the manual that corresponds to your Maria Db server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s)' at line 1`

The line that is read by my script shows `b'2020-06-12 15:30:00.100,13.3,3.1,5.1\n'` with `print(last_line)`

Comment: `2020-06-12 15:31:00,13.3,3.1,5,1` I don't understand this line; it has 4 commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query is not well formatted because you're looking to add four values, while `last_line` is just a string. Try using `str.split()` to make sure all four values are understood:

```
cursor.execute(query, last_line.split(","))
```

Comment: Damn, that was easy. Did not thought about that. I had to add an encode to the subprocess because it was giving me bytes not string. But apart from that the .split did the trick. Thx